# Resource.String does not contain a definition for 'MyString'

Tags: android, string, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm learning how to create a decent Xamarin Android app, but I can't get something as simple as this to work:

```
Toast.MakeText(this, GetString(Resource.String.salir_aplicacion), ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

I have added the string at strings.xml

```
<string name="salir_aplicacion"> ¿ Seguro que quieres salir de la aplicación?</string>
```

But I always have ".salir_aplicacion" marked as an error because it can't find a definition.

I have tried different ways that I have seen on the internet or other questions, but I can't solve the compilation problem, and I think it's because of some silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved the `strings.xml` file?

Based on the code you provided, I created a project:

MainActivity.cs

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn).Click += MainActivity_Click;
    }

    private void MainActivity_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, GetString(Resource.String.salir_aplicacion), ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
    ....
}
```

strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App2</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="salir_aplicacion"> ¿ Seguro que quieres salir de la aplicación?</string>
</resources>
```

And this is the [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEM1N.jpg).

**Update:**

According to what you described: It will error, when you use clone project. If it's OK, I suggest you migrate the useful code in GitHub project to the new project.

Comment: yes, I did. Do you not get an error when writing that? Specifically, here: .salir_aplicacion

Comment: @pablosimón *Do you not get an error when writing that? Specifically, here: .salir_aplicacion?* No

Comment: @pablosimón Have you tried creating a new project to see if the problem persists? BTW, my android version is 13.

Comment: I just did it now and the problem did not persist. Now the problem is that the project I'm working on is a GitHub clone for the project I am working on at my job

Comment: @pablosimón Do you mean that if you create a new project, the problem will not exist but the previous project still has problems?

Comment: Yes, that's what's happening.

Comment: @pablosimón If it's OK, I suggest you migrate the useful code in GitHub project to the new project.

Comment: I suppose I'll have to do that. Thank you very much.